# Does changing mass change projectile speed?

Tags: projectile, speed

If a projectile is fires from a pistol with 10g mass, and somehow during flight it's mass is increased to 1000g, how does this affect it's projectile speed?  (This is a DnD hypothetical question).

I assume that when the mass increases, the force that's behind it that's keeping it going will no longer be enough to keep the speed, and it's speed will drop.

Comment: You have to be more specific than “somehow”.  What is the source of the extra mass?

Comment: ...E.g., did it merge in flight with 99 other bullets that also were moving on parallel trajectories at the same speed? Or did it slam into a _non-moving_ mass of 990g?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it a DnD question.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is basically correct. First to clarify terms, we have a bullet that has been fired and is traveling at a constant speed - after the bullet leaves the gun, there is no horizontal force acting on it (let's ignore the vertical direction for simplicity). One way we can double the bullet's mass by having it collide with another, stationary bullet. This will be an inelastic collision, so the bullets collide and stick together, and move away as a single projectile with twice the mass. In this situation, momentum is conserved ($p = mv$). As the mass doubles, the speed is halved.

Since this is a DnD question, I assume the bullet just grows in size due to magic. In that case, there isn't any stationary mass that has to be brought up to speed, in which case the bullet won't slow down. Here, you get energy "for free" since the more massive bullet has more momentum that didn't really come from anywhere. But hey, it's magic - it can work however you define it. Maybe the wizard expends energy enlarging the moving projectile, and the bullet doesn't slow down after all. Be forewarned, though, attempting to apply real-life physics to roleplaying games can be fraught with peril, see the [Peasant Railgun](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/Peasant_Railgun).

Comment: Gravity acts on the bullet!

Comment: Two identical magnetic bullets of mass m are fired along nearly identical trajectories with velocity v.  if the trajectories slowly converge such that the bullets come together due to magnetic attraction, are you saying the bullets instantaneously change their speed from v to 1/2 v

Comment: @jmh They'll inelastically collide and their combined final velocity will be a vector halfway between the two original velocity vectors, both in direction and magnitude.

Comment: @Ryan_L, thanks. I know you are right, I guess I hadn't thought of it quite like that. Just thinking of the problem as i stated it made me pause.

Comment: @jmh No, because in that case both bullets are moving and have momenutm $mv$ (total momentum $2mv$), so after they connect they still move at $v$ (total momentum still $2mv$). Ryan is correct that the final velocity vector will be halfway between the original two velocity vectors, but since those  two are near-identical, the velocity vector will be basically unchanged. In my example, the second bullet is *not* moving, so one bullet has momentum $mv$ and the other has momentum $0$. After they collide, the combined projectile still has momentum $mv$, but has twice the mass and half the velocity.

Comment: @NuclearWang, of course,  you are right.  Thanks.